# PyDev does not recognize imports

Tags: python, eclipse, import, pydev

I am using PyDev for Eclipse, and shows a few red underlines as erros for wrong imports. However, these imports work. I can start the script with F9, and use the Classes from these modules just fine. The red line is bothering me however, plus I cannot use the autocomplete for these imports. How can I force Eclipse PyDev to reevaluate the modules in the project?

I already refreshed my `PYTHONPATH` with `python27/site_packages` in it.

Example of red underlines under correct imports:

[image: Example of red underlines under correct imports]

The module `PerClustering.py` exists:

[image: The module PerClustering.py exists]

The module `PerClustering.py` contains a class `PerClustering`:

[image: The module PerClustering.py contains a class PerClustering]

The other imports do not show red lines. These modules are however in the same directories (or actually namespaces, since the directories contain an empty `__init__.py` file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this code works elsewhere and the directory is in tact, you probably just have to rebuild which is pretty common with eclipse projects. To achieve this, navigate to the rebuild option under **Project >> Clean**.

**EDIT:** It is unlikely, but you may have to restart eclipse in order to make it work.

Comment: A project Clean+Build was not enough, but a subsequent restart of Eclipse seems to do the trick.

Comment: Really? That is interesting. I never have to restart my IDE after rebuilding but there you go. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Python interpreter may not be set up correctly.

To correct this, go to *Eclipse Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters > Python Interpreter*, then select *New* to add the correct Python interpreter. Finally hit *Apply and Close*. You may have to re-open the editors.

In my case (macOS), the default was the Python 2 interpreter at `/usr/bin/python`, and I had to add the Python 3 interpreter from `/usr/bin/python3`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after certifying that the directory was added to the `PATH`, I did not need to restart the Eclipse, I just had to rewrite the `from line`, so that the `IDE` recognizes the directory with the `intelisense`. **This is, if the red squiggles are still there**.

- **NOTE**: The libraries need to be added into *External Libraires* inside *PyDev - PYTHONPATH*