# Eclipse/PyDev/Django not recognizing project app imports

Tags: python, django, eclipse, import

Found something on SO, but couldn't solve my problem, it is slightly different from the ones I saw..

So, here's the deal, I have a Django project, and it runs perfectly..
I'm using Eclipse for IDLE, and there's the problem..

In `urls.py` and others, I have to import files from the Django Apps..

Like `from app1 import views` or in 1 app `from app1.forms import Form1`

And Eclipse gives me `Unresolved import`

If I change it to (using the example above) `from projectname.app1 import views` or `from projectname.app1.forms import Form1`, the error goes away, but then I get an error when I run the project:

```
ImportError: No module named 'projectname.app1'
```

What I have done:
Already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235307/pydev-does-not-recognize-imports), but with no success..Project, Clean, Reset, and nothing..